# Displaying localised dates in tkinter label results in mangled text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, unicode

I'm putting a localised date string in a label. This works fine in English, but when I use `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "it_IT")` to format the date in Italian, the results are mangled:

[image: Incorrect output when using setlocale]

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import locale
from datetime import date

root = Tk()
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "it_IT")
today = date.today().strftime('%A %d %B')
Label(root, text=today, bg='black', fg='white', font=("arial", 35)).pack()

root.mainloop()][1]
```

The `ì` (`i` with accent) is displayed as `Ã¬` there.

I'm using Python 3.6

If I use `text="Lunedì 03 Dicembre" in the`Label()` call directly the output is correct.

Why is the output being messed up?

[image: Correct output when entering literal string]

Comment: Added the images and added Python version. I'll check with another machine in the meantime

Comment: macOS Mojave it is. I'll update my python now

Comment: Ah, your second screenshot shows you are still using `setlocale()` to get the string formatted, but you used the literal directly. So the value that `strftime()` returns is the mojibake here.

Comment: It is the locale setting itself that is the issue. Can you run the command `locale` on the command line? I suspect that `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "it_IT.UTF-8")` would fix this issue, but I want to be sure and see the default you currently have configured.

Comment: Ok my default is it_IT.UTF-8, i updated the code... to no luck

Comment: What does `locale` output?

Comment: > locale
LANG="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Any reason you are not just using `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME,'')` to pick up the current setting? And what does `locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_FMT)` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a more specific locale, one with the codepage to encode characters included:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "it_IT.UTF-8")
```

I suspect that your system default is set to `ISO8859-15` or `ISO8859-1` and the UTF-8-encoded day name is decoded with either of those codecs instead.

Comment: I updated the code and Python to vers. 3.7.1.. Still wrong. This is driving me crazy

Comment: I updated my Python, now added the UTF-8 and it works... btw, `locale.LC_TIME, ' ')` just returns in English